# Prevent normalizing of the model name by overriding 'normalizeModelName' in Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to prevent normalizing (dasherized by convention) of the model name and instead use the original name. I want to override the function 'normalizeModelName' as the page http://emberjs.com/api/data/#method_normalizeModelName suggests that this should be possible. But i'm not able to do so.

Simply assigning a new function to DS.normalizeModelName is returning an error: `Cannot assign to read only property 'normalizeModelName' of object '[object Object]'`.

How could I prevent normalizing of the (internal) model name?

Comment: At first, I thought you can reopen every object to improve its methods, but apparently, you can't. Are you sure you can't solve your primary problem with custom adapters/serializers or custom-inflector-rules? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: It's possible to solve a part of the problem using a custom serializer and adapter. But I have to create a serializer for every model to change the payloadKeyFromModelName function which returns a hard-coded model name (because the original name is not available anymore).
But still a problem exists in our use-case where there are two models registered with the same name because of the normalize method (for example ("Messages" and "messages" are both normalized to "messages" internally).

Comment: Well, maybe it's faster and easier for you to make a small refactoring and rename models? You see, ember likes `convention over configuration`  thing, so if you do as ember says - everything's ok, but if you turn left or right - it will be nearly impossible or impossible at all to make the project work. Ember suggests to name models in dasherized style (and every other file, mostly, as I remember). I mean, you took a huge risk when named your models this way, probably the best option for you right now - rename them.

Comment: That will unfortunately not work for us because the models are generated based on a predefined list of models which is used in an existing application as well. 
In my opinion it's totally unnecessary to change the model name internally to apply the convention for model names. I think that in case of naming it should always be a recommendation to follow the convention and not to enforce a convention by changing the name.

Comment: Next to that I think convention over configuration only works if you're able to change the convention to your own needs if necessary. So therefore I would like to override the normalizeModelName function.

Comment: @Lebbers did you find a solution for this already? i currently have a similar problem except in my case i have to normalize using a lookup table due to a non spec compliant jsonapi with model names like: `foo_barNom` that i cannot change :/ i already think about reimplementing some ember data core stuff :\ the api does not even have `included`.. they ship data inside `relationships`...

Comment: overriding `modelNameFromPayloadType` within the `JSONAPISerializer.extend` seems to be a good start https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.10.0/addon/serializers/json-api.js#L674-L676

Comment: keyForRelationship is important too if you describe relationships through the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**small warning: this is related to 2.10.0**
*i will not guarantee compatibility beyond or below this version. you need to dig through the corresponding files yourself.*

since i had a similar problem i dug through the sourcecode of some ember-data stuff and came to the following conclusion:

you need to extend `DS.JSONAPIAdapter` with `pathForType(name)` wich essentially takes the name and camelizes as well as pluralizes it before it's being returned as plain text string.

this usually converts model names from `foo-bar` to `fooBars` by doing this: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.10.0/addon/adapters/json-api.js#L134-L137

now about the opposite:

you need to extend `DS.JSONAPISerializer` with `keyForRelationship(key, typeClass, method)`

where `key` is essentially the model name aquired from relationships in your models. like: `fooBar`

this usually translates to `foo-bar` by simply doing `return dasherize(key);` https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.10.0/addon/serializers/json-api.js#L453-L455

you might to also dig through some other methods inside the serializer: `modelNameFromPayloadKey` `modelNameFromPayloadType` `payloadKeyFromModelName` `payloadTypeFromModelName`

just throw in some `debugger;` lines to see whats going through.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't had the time to response to your comment on my question yet but I did something similar as your suggestion here. The only thing i've added is an `originalName` property to my models, which I lookup if needed (e.g. `this.store.modelFor(modelName).originalName;`). 
I've added this because in a particular case the normalized name was used instead of the "original name".